# Inline Javascript not functioning in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events, dreamweaver, onmouseover

I have a DIV  that contains some buttons (divs) each button is set to `onmouseover` change the properties of all the corresponding divs. I used the Dreamweaver behaviors thing to create this because I am incredibly new at Javascript. Well my issue is; it works perfectly in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari... but does nothing in Internet Explorer. I have know idea where to start.  the website in question  [here](http://www.glamourpawscollars.com)

Comment: This is perfectly normal in the javascript development cycle.  It's called the 20-80 rule.  The first 20% of your time is spent getting your code to work, and the remaining 80% is spent getting it to work on IE.

Comment: thanks for the heads up -_- I dont understand why microsoft insists on making their browser only recognize unique standards.

Comment: Because they care about backwards compatibility and web-apps (like hta) before most of 'us' where thinking about it. Being bashed around by firefox for the last year made me re-respect IE.. sadly. Most of the things Firefox once warned us about that microsoft 'would' do to us, has now been done to us by firefox themselves. Now, ff is just destroying (access to) the engine that the web has been built upon for the last half decade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're problem is in this function:

```
function MM_changeProp(objId,x,theProp,theValue) { //v9.0
  var obj = null; with (document){ if (getElementById)
  obj = getElementById(objId); }
  if (obj){
    if (theValue == true || theValue == false)
      eval("obj.style."+theProp+"="+theValue);
    else eval("obj.style."+theProp+"='"+theValue+"'");
  }
}
```

specifically, this line:

```
else eval("obj.style."+theProp+"='"+theValue+"'");
```

IE8 ends up choking when you try to change the `backgroundImage` property, it attempts to eval:

```
obj.style.backgroundImage=' url(../images/homepointer1.png)'
```

and throws

```
SCRIPT87: Invalid argument.
```

I think it's because you have an extra space in the value and didn't use quotes around the URL string.  Basically where you have something like this in your code:

```
' url(../images/homepointer2.png)'
```

You need to fix it so it looks like this:

```
'url("../images/homepointer2.png")'
```

I didn't have an easy way to verify this, so the fix might not be right, but it's definitely where your problem is.  By the way, it's only broken in IE7/IE8, it works great in IE9.

Comment: hmm, tried that and it broke it in all browsers! how did you find the error?

Comment: ok so after looking again the problem was simply the space in the value! thanks.